# Is there a way to Timelock Data Encryption with AES SH-256?

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography, aes, bitcoin

Is there a way with to encrypt data in a file with a *Timelock* feature? The *Timelock* feature will act as gatekeeper so the decryption will not proceed and data will not be display until specific(flexible) DateTimeOffset in the future?

User will need to wait until a certain date in the future, then program will auto decrypt itself by signing a micro transaction(*Timelock* via DateTimeOffset auto decryption with a transaction unlock on blockchain).

### Requirements:

- Ideally the *Timelock* DateTimeOffset/transaction unlock should be coming from and external source(Bitcoin blockchain).
- The *TimeLock* feature should not be a simple *if/else* clause that can be defeated easily if decompile.
- A program decompile should also not reveal the decryption key.

### I am considering using:

- Bitcoin blockchain with 10 minutes block time to calculate an approximate DateTime countdown so it can't be faked. See Peter Todd project timelock: https://github.com/petertodd/timelock
- ConfuserEx 2 Obfuscator: https://github.com/mkaring/ConfuserEx

> Could I use the bitcoin blockchain lock and unlock fund operation with
>   signature as a mecanisme to encrypt/decrypt the file data?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is no, not the way you're trying to do it.

Once the ciphertext is out there, it doesn't change. It's just a piece of data. You can't make a piece of data that changes at a given time. You can make a program that acts differently based on the time, but that's no good if whoever runs it can give it a different time, either by controlling the clock or by modifying the excution of the program.

Cryptography is based on knowledge. If somebody can't decrypt something, it's because they lack knowledge, namely, knowledge of the decryption key. How could someone learn the decryption key at a given time?

The only solution is **key escrow**: give the key to a trusted third party, with the instruction to release the key only at a given time.

There is a way to make a time lock without a trusted third party, but by its nature, it's very approximative. You can't make a time lock that will be unlocked at a precise date. You can make a time lock that will, if you're lucky, be unlocked within a given decade. This works by providing some data from which the decryption key can be calculated, but with a very high calculation cost. Obviously the time it takes to break the lock will depend on how fast a computer the attacker is willing to buy.

For more information, see [Time capsule cryptography?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/606/time-capsule-cryptography) and [Time Based encryption](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/time-based-encryption).

Comment: Thank you Gilles for your answer. Is there a way to use the bitcoin proof of work calculation power plus the blockchain to create this timelock mecanisme in your knowledge?

Comment: @HugoDoyon [No](http://doyouneedablockchain.com/)